# Reversing a double linked list with Swift

Tags: swift, linked-list

I have the code below to reverse a double linked list using Swift. However, I am confused on whether the `swap` function is swapping the `currentNode` with the node adjacent to it? or is it swapping it's two adjacent nodes?

*Example:
Linked List values representation:* 1 -> 2 -> 3

Is it swapping 1 and 2 on the first run? or is it swapping 1 and 3? which values get swapped on the first run?

```
public func reverse() {
    var node = head
    while let currentNode = node {
        node = currentNode.next
        swap(&currentNode.next, &currentNode.previous)
        head = currentNode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The swap call here swaps references to the next and previous element. Because when you're reverting a doubly linked list all "next" pointers should become "previous" and vice versa.

Take a look at this image for example
[image]

And imagine that you need to change the marks on the arrows (next should become prev, prev should become next).

Comment: but on the first run, isn't A.prev = null?

Comment: @Maria9905 It is. And when you swap the values you get A.next = null - because your first element becomes your last element.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a print statement inside the loop (with a newline) to help you debug, or use the debugger to add a breakpoint.

We can go through the function together to manually debug as well to improve understanding:

First run:

```
public func reverse() {
    var node = head
    while let currentNode = node {
        node = currentNode.next
        swap(&currentNode.next, &currentNode.previous)
        head = currentNode
    }
}
```

In this function:

1. You assign `node` to `head`. They're both pointing to the node with the value `1`
2. if `node` exists (it does), then assign `currentNode` to `node`, so `currentNode = node`, therefore `currentNode = 1 and node = 1 and head = 1` (all the same node)
3. (In the `while`): you say, `node = currentNode.next`. So now `node` is `2`
4. `currentNode = 1` still. `currentNode.previous` is `nil`, and `currentNode.next` is `2`.
5. After the swap, the list looks like: `2 -> nil (->) 3` (I put the -> in parens because it doesn't actually "point" to 3 since it's nil).

**Note that when I say `=` or *is*, above, like in `node = 2`, I mean "`node` variable is referring to the Node object with the value of 2"**

So we're actually swapping the the first node's previous and next.